# SSRS Subscription in SQL Agent Failing - Unable to determine if the owner of job has server access

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I have done much searching on this without a solid solution.

I just set up a new SSRS instance on the same server as my SQL 2016 instance. Everything is running fine report wise, etc. The problem is that when a report is scheduled, it creates a Sql Agent Job in SQL Server, and the SQL Agent is erroring out with the following:

> The job failed. Unable to determine if the owner
>   (MyDomain\ReportService) of job 17F8E31D-0838-4829-8C3C-E3FE5BBD3483
>   has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows
>   NT group/user 'MyDomain\ReportService', error code 0x5. [SQLSTATE
>   42000] (Error 15404)).

**Current setup:**

1. SSRS using an Active Directory account as the service account called
   Report Service
2. Sql Server 2016 Engine is using an Active Directory account as the service
   account called SqlService
3. Both SSRS and SQL Database are on the same machine
4. I double checked that SqlService is SysAdmin and has all other
   permissions, and non-SSRS jobs run fine

**From my research, I can solve this in one of three ways:**

1. Change the SSRS SQL Agent job created by SSRS to be owned by SA (by
       default the job is owned by MyDomain\ReportService). The problem
       with this is that I would have to do this every time a user creates
       a new subscription via SSRS or create an ongoing script because SSRS
       by default will use the service as the owner. And I KNOW that this
       was not done at my previous employer.
2. I could make the SqlService a
       domain administrator. I don't want to do this for security reasons,
       obviously.
3. I could give the SqlService "SeImpersonatePrivilege"
       (Impersonate a client after login) on my domain via the security
       policy. This also works, but there seems like there would be a
       better way, and I would think this is also a security risk as
       setting this doesn't explicitly limit SqlService to only
       impersonating the ReportService.

**So, my question is hopefully from those who have set SSRS up, what is the best practice for allowing SQL Server to run the SSRS subscriptions?** It's possible that something in our environment is messed up permissions wise, but I guess mostly I'm looking for advice on how *should* this be set up. Thank you greatly in advance.

Comment: Which service acct? SSRS or SqlAgent?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused and only just now realized your question is referencing my answer below. I'm referring to the SQL Server service account. So, it's the one called **Sql Server** if viewing from the **Sql Server Configuration Manager**. I didn't need to do anything with the Sql Agent or the SSRS accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that we had some kind of limitation on the active directory rights of the service account. I wasn't unable to pinpoint the exact permissions, but after adding the account to a group that explicitly allowed viewing active directory users and groups, it worked. So, this was due to abnormal limitations for basic domain user rights.

Comment: We also found that if `SqlService` is disabled, but the SQL Engine service hasn't been restarted in a while, you'll get this error. Re-enabling `SqlService` in AD solves the problem without requiring a restart of anything.

Answer (score -1):

[Link](https://www.risual.com/2013/03/01/could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-groupuser-domainuser-error-code-0x5-sqlstate-42000-error-15404-connisloginsysadmin/)

From the site listed above:

Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user ‘domainuser’, error code 0x5. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)(ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)

**The solution to this is to add the SQL Server service account to the ‘BUILTINWindows Authorization Access Group’ on your DC.**

You can then run “EXECUTE AS USER = ‘domainuser’” on SQL Server to check.